# Int to boolean array python

Tags: python, byte, ascii, bit, bitwise-and

If I have a char d and a char k, how do I turn each into a bit array (such as True-False-True-True-True-False-False-True) and then combine the arrays into a single array by AND-ing each bit (and then turning the combined array back into a char)?  Such as 01100001 (a) and 01100011 (c) combine to make 01100001 (c)?  Also, sometimes the results of these conversions are not ASCII (such as 00000010)?

Comment: 00000010, ^B, is indeed ASCII, just not printable

Comment: and why turn them into a bit array? just and the numbers

Comment: Part of asking good questions is asking what you really want to know about. Don't assume more about how to solve the problem than you really need to. Here, you want the bitwise-AND of the two characters; "turning them into bit arrays" is a useless diversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no need to make an array:

```
>>> chr(ord('c') & ord('a'))
'a'
```